# Aplicar estilo em texto de um RichEdit no Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

Eu preciso **negritar** algumas palavras dentro de um *RichEdit* no Delphi, ele funciona normalmente quando não há quebra de linha. Porém quando insiro uma quebra de linha eu não consigo selecionar corretamente a palavra para aplicar o estilo.

Todos os exemplos que encontrei estão com o mesmo problema.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Neste exemplo](http://maikelscheid.blogspot.com.br/2009/01/destacando-palavra-no-richedit.html) ele armazena as palavras que serão negritadas e a cor que terão e ao digitar ele vai aplicando a formatação. Porém só funciona até inserir uma quebra de linha.

```
procedure TfrmRichEdit.RichEdit1KeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
const
   LetrasValidas = ['a'..'z', 'A'..'Z', '0'..'9', '<', '>', '!', '='];

var
   iPosIni: Integer;
   iPosFim: Integer;
   iSelStart: Integer;
   iSelLength: Integer;
   iLoopFor: Integer;
   sText: string;
begin
   LockWindowUpdate(RichEdit1.Handle);

   // Guardaremos a posição inicial
   iSelStart := RichEdit1.SelStart;
   iSelLength := RichEdit1.SelLength;

   sText := RichEdit1.Text;

   // Acharemos o inicio da palavra
   iPosIni := iSelStart;
   if sText[iPosIni] in LetrasValidas then
   begin
      for iLoopFor := iSelStart - 1 downto 0 do
      begin
         if sText[iLoopFor] in LetrasValidas then
            iPosIni := iLoopFor
         else
            Break;
      end;
   end;

   // Acharemos o final da palavra
   iPosFim := iSelStart;
   for iLoopFor := iSelStart + 1 to Length(RichEdit1.Text) do
   begin
      if RichEdit1.Text[iLoopFor] in LetrasValidas then
         iPosFim := iLoopFor
      else
         Break;
   end;

   // Selecionaremos a palavra
   RichEdit1.SelStart := iPosIni - 1;
   RichEdit1.SelLength := (iPosFim) - RichEdit1.SelStart;

   // setaremos a cor original e estilo original
   RichEdit1.SelAttributes.Color := clBlack;
   RichEdit1.SelAttributes.Style := [];

   // Atribuiremos a nova cor e estilo caso encontre a palavra
   for iLoopFor := 0 to High(APalavras) do
   begin
      if UpperCase(APalavras[iLoopFor].DS_PALAVRA) = UpperCase(RichEdit1.SelText) then
      begin
         RichEdit1.SelAttributes.Color := APalavras[iLoopFor].VR_COR;
         RichEdit1.SelAttributes.Style := APalavras[iLoopFor].ESTILO;
         Break;
      end;
   end;

   // Posicionaremos o cursor na posição original
   RichEdit1.SelStart := iSelStart;
   RichEdit1.SelLength := iSelLength;

   LockWindowUpdate(0);
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que eu pude identificar ao debugar o código que você colocou, o problema é que cada quebra de linha adiciona um caractere especial invisível (o caractere `CR` ou `#13#10`).

A cada nova quebra de linha a contagem vai se perdendo cada vez mais. A solução é contar quantas quebras de linha existem do inicio do texto até a posição atual do cursor e então subtrair esse número de quebras de linha do valor de `RichEdit1.SelStart`.

Para fazer essa contagem eu criei um método (criei rapidão, então sei que daria pra melhorar kkk) e uso ele dentro do `OnKeyUp`.

**MÉTODO QUE CONTA AS QUEBRAS DE LINHA:**

```
function TfrmRichEdit.GetCrCount(const pText: string; const pPosition: Integer): Integer;
var
  lPos: Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;

  lPos := 1;
  while lPos < pPosition do
  begin
    lPos := Pos(#13#10, pText, lPos);
    if (lPos = 0) or (lPos >= pPosition) then
    begin
      Break;
    end
    else
    begin
      inc(Result);
      inc(lPos);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Agora que temos o método que conta as quebras de linha, vamos aplicar seu uso no `OnKeyUp` que você postou:

**ATENÇÃO:** As alterações que eu fiz estão indicadas com esses marcadores:

`<<<<< PONTO 1 >>>>>` `<<<<< PONTO 2 >>>>>` `<<<<< PONTO 3 >>>>>`

**SEU MÉTODO *ONKEYUP()* COM AS MINHAS ALTERAÇÕES**

```
procedure TfrmRichEdit.RichEdit1KeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
const
  LetrasValidas = ['a'..'z', 'A'..'Z', '0'..'9', '<', '>', '!', '='];

var
  iPosIni: Integer;
  iPosFim: Integer;
  iSelStart: Integer;
  iSelLength: Integer;
  iLoopFor: Integer;
  lCountCr: Integer;
  sText: string;
begin
  LockWindowUpdate(RichEdit1.Handle);

  // Guardaremos a posição inicial
  iSelStart := RichEdit1.SelStart;
  iSelLength := RichEdit1.SelLength;

  sText := RichEdit1.Text;

  // Acharemos o inicio da palavra
  iPosIni := iSelStart;
  if sText[iPosIni] in LetrasValidas then
  begin
    for iLoopFor := iSelStart - 1 downto 0 do
    begin
      if sText[iLoopFor] in LetrasValidas then
        iPosIni := iLoopFor
      else
        Break;
    end;
  end;

  // Acharemos o final da palavra
  iPosFim := iSelStart;
  for iLoopFor := iSelStart + 1 to Length(RichEdit1.Text) do
  begin
    if RichEdit1.Text[iLoopFor] in LetrasValidas then
      iPosFim := iLoopFor
    else
      Break;
  end;

  // <<<<< PONTO 1 >>>>>
  // ***( OBTENHO A CONTAGEM DE QUEBRAS DE LINHA )***
  lCountCr := GetCrCount(sText, iSelStart);
  // ************************************************

  // Selecionaremos a palavra
  // <<<<< PONTO 2 >>>>>
  // ***( SUBTRAIO O NÚMERO DE QUEBRAS DE LINHA )***
  //RichEdit1.SelStart := iPosIni - 1;
  //RichEdit1.SelLength := (iPosFim) - RichEdit1.SelStart;
  RichEdit1.SelStart := iPosIni - 1 - lCountCr;
  RichEdit1.SelLength := (iPosFim) - RichEdit1.SelStart - lCountCr;
  // ***********************************************

  // setaremos a cor original e estilo original
  RichEdit1.SelAttributes.Color := clBlack;
  RichEdit1.SelAttributes.Style := [];

  // Atribuiremos a nova cor e estilo caso encontre a palavra
  for iLoopFor := 0 to High(APalavras) do
  begin
    // <<<<< PONTO 3 >>>>>
    // ***( REMOVO OS ESPAÇOS ANTES E DEPOIS PARA OTIMIZAR A COMPARAÇÃO )***
    //if UpperCase(APalavras[iLoopFor].DS_PALAVRA) = UpperCase(RichEdit1.SelText) then
    if Trim(UpperCase(APalavras[iLoopFor].DS_PALAVRA)) = Trim(UpperCase(RichEdit1.SelText)) then
    // *********************************************************************
    begin
      RichEdit1.SelAttributes.Color := APalavras[iLoopFor].VR_COR;
      RichEdit1.SelAttributes.Style := APalavras[iLoopFor].ESTILO;
      Break;
    end;
  end;

  // Posicionaremos o cursor na posição original
  RichEdit1.SelStart := iSelStart;
  RichEdit1.SelLength := iSelLength;

  LockWindowUpdate(0);
end;
```

Comment: O código ficou interessante. Porém existem algumas situações em que ele não aplica o estilo corretamente. Por exemplo: se eu digito uma palavra que está na lista, ele aplica o estilo, dai eu quebro uma linha digito a mesma palavra, ele aplica o estilo, dai se eu quebro uma linha e digito alguma palavra que não está na lista já não funciona mais depois dela. Não consegui identificar o problema ainda.

Comment: Acertei o ponto 2, da uma olhada lá.

Comment: Tá ficando redondinho. rs Mas ainda continua com uns problemas pra aplicar o estilo. Por exemplo: após digitar algumas linhas ele começa aplicar um estilo quando começo digitar e às vezes quando termino de digitar a palavra ele não aplica o estilo correspondente, e se vou apagando a palavra ele mantém o estilo.
Outra situação é quando eu tenho algumas palavras digitadas, dai se eu apago uma no início ele perde o estilo de tudo.

Comment: Mas cara, vc quer que eu faça o software inteiro pra vc? Eu não to desenvolvendo o aplicativo, eu abro o Delphi, testo, acho o problema, te respondo e fecho sem salvar. Seu problema era a quebra de linha, já está resolvido. Acho que já te indiquei o caminho das pedras e agora vc toca o barco, isso aí é ajustezinho que vc vai ter que fazer.

Comment: Hora nenhuma te pedi pra desenvolver tudo. Da mesma forma eu estou fazendo testes aqui e tentando corrigir você fez e conseguiu corrigir. Isso é só uma parte da solução que estou precisando. Agradeço muito a ajuda. Vou marcar como resolvido aqui.